# What is command line to install Cyberghost in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, vpn

The version of my Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS. I intend to install a free VPN, and it seems that CyberGhost is one of the free and good VPNs. May you please guide me about the command line in terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using CyberGhost since May 2021.  I am on a 3 year subscription.  BEWARE that cyberghost does not work on Ubuntu versions above 20.04.  I have written to the technical department and the reply was "Please don't worry since our developers are still improving our application for the Linux Operating system, and a possible app that will be compatible with all versions of Linux, might be released soon. Although, we can't provide an exact time frame when it will be released or implemented"  I received this reply a year ago, and again when I enquired recently, and was given exactly the same answer.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP has a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1221680)

Answer (score 1):

I just edited the **install.sh** and changed one of the version checks to 22.04 and 2.35. It *seems* to be working fine. You can check your glibc version by typing **ldd --version**

```
# check if GLIBC version is compatible
if [ "$ubuntuDistroVersion" == "22.04" ]; then

        if [ "$glibcVersion" == "2.35" ] ; then
```

Answer (score 0):

use the official installation manual:

https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020436274-How-to-install-CyberGhost-on-Linux

1. go into "My devices" and "Configure New Device"
2. Select your OS and download the installer
3. extract the zip file
4. go into Terminal and cd to the folder that was extracted from the zip
5. once you are in the directory with the install file do:

   ```
   sudo bash install.sh
   ```
6. answer the questions from the istaller until istallation is complete
7. see the options for starting the vpn with:

   ```
   cyberghostvpn
   ```

Comment: Hey totalynotanoob! I would like to quote from [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Comment: @RandomPerson will do

Answer (score 0):

How I make Cyberghostvpn to work in Ubuntu 22.04.

Install Ubuntu 20.04,Install Cyberghostvpn and configure it and then upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 from Softwareupdater.

Worked fine with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).